# Javascript Automatic Update Total

Tags: javascript, ajax

I am trying to update total price for a few selected options. The code is developed by someone else and I know that it has been working for others for a long time. However it just will not work for me. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Below are the code I use:

HTML

```
<form name="cart_quantity" action="" method="post">    
  <h4>Available Options</h4>
  <p>
    <input type="hidden" id="hid_id[7]" value="0"> <select id="id[7]" name="id[7]" required aria-required="true" onchange="changePrice(this.id)" class="form-control">
      <option value="" selected="selected">--- Please Select ---</option>
      <option value="48">1 x nVidia RTX 2080 Ti 11GB GDDR6 blower fan design (+$1,800.00)</option>
      <option value="49">2 x nVidia RTX 2080 Ti 11GB GDDR6 bblower fan design (+$3,600.00)</option>
      <option value="50">3 x nVidia RTX 2080 Ti 11GB GDDR6 blower fan design (+$5,400.00)</option>
      <option value="51">4 x nVidia RTX 2080 Ti 11GB GDDR6 blower fan design (+$7,200.00)</option>
      <option value="27">Not required</option>
    </select>
  </p>

  <p>Options sub-total: <span id="productPrice"></span></p> 
</form>
```

Javascript

```
  var actualprice = document.getElementById('productPrice').innerHTML;
  var actualInd = actualprice.indexOf("(");
  var price = actualprice.substring(actualInd + 1, (actualprice.length));
  var total = price.match(/[\+\-]*(\d+)\.(\d+)/)[0];

  function changePrice(id) {
    var select_list_field = document.getElementById(id);
    var select_list_selected_index = select_list_field.selectedIndex;
    var text = select_list_field.options[select_list_selected_index].text;

    var ind = text.indexOf("(") + 1;
    var str = text.substring(ind, text.indexOf(")"));
    if (str != '') {
      str = str.replace(',', ''); //Removes comma - added in version 1.2.1
      str = str.replace('$', ''); //Removes $ - added in version 1.2.3
      str = str.match(/[\+\-]*(\d+)\.(\d+)/)[0];
    };
    var hFieldId = "hid_" + id;
    var hiddenField = document.getElementById(hFieldId).value;
    if (str == "select") {
      if (isNaN(hiddenField)) {} else {
        total = total - hiddenField;
      };
      document.getElementById(hFieldId).value = 0;
    } else {
      document.getElementById(hFieldId).value = str;
      if (hiddenField > 0 || hiddenField < 0) {
        total = total - hiddenField;
      };
      if (isNaN(str) || (str.length === 0)) {
        total = parseFloat(total);
      } else {
        total = parseFloat(str) + parseFloat(total);
      };
      //    added v.1.2.3 - sanity check - keeps total from showing negative
      var $total_display = 0;
      if (total < 0) {
        total_display = 0;
      } else {
        total_display = total;
      }
    }
    document.getElementById('productPrice').innerHTML = actualprice.replace(/[\+\-]*(\d+)\.(\d+)/, total_display.toFixed(2).replace(/(\d)(?=(\d{3})+\.)/g, "$1,")); //Version 1.2.3
  }
```

Comment: `  var total = price.match(/[\+\-]*(\d+)\.(\d+)/)[0]; ` <-- this is failing, make it more robust and you would be able to fix it yourself

Answer (score 0):

First of all, next time please include what you did try so far.
Oke, because your new i will try to explain a few thing.

The next piece of code is, to me, not well constructed,

```
var actualprice = document.getElementById('productPrice').innerHTML;
var actualInd = actualprice.indexOf("(");
var price = actualprice.substring(actualInd + 1, (actualprice.length));
var total = price.match(/[\+\-]*(\d+)\.(\d+)/)[0];
```

Adding ´if statement´ and default values helps you to debug and keep it running.

```
var actualprice, actualInd, price, total, total_check;
actualprice = document.getElementById('productPrice').innerHTML;
actualInd = actualprice.indexOf("(");
if (actualprice.length === 0) {
    actualprice = 0;
    console.warning("idiot html usage ");
}

if (actualInd < 0) {
    actualInd = 0;
    console.warning("strange indexOf usage ");
}


price = actualprice.substring(actualInd + 1, (actualprice.length));
total_check = price.match(/[\+\-]*(\d+)\.(\d+)/);

if (!total_check) {
    total = total_check[0];
} else {
    console.error("something went wrong");
}
```

Also the getting all information by pulling everything around in your DOM is to me not an option.

Example:

```
  <option value="" selected="selected">--- Please Select ---</option>
  <option value="48">1 x nVidia RTX 2080 Ti 11GB GDDR6 blower fan design (+$1,800.00)</option>


actualprice.indexOf("(");
```

Wouldn't be more neat like this ?

```
 <option value="48" data-price-tag="18000.00">1 x nVidia RTX 2080 Ti 11GB GDDR6 blower fan design (+$1,800.00)</option>

price = <element selection>.dataset.priceTag;
```

For me at least there is a notable few things wrong with that script.
I will give you a few links that i think can and would help you to understand things better if you like.

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/dataset
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Console

Comment: Thanks a lot for the reply. I will look at the dataset.